# Python Pandas to sqlite

Tags: sqlite, python, sqlalchemy

Hello I am new I had a question so I am trying to create a simple api using flask ..

the data I have is in CSV and I want to import it in to SQLlite file .. which I have done. and can access the data 
 after I data is loaded  and I have conformed there is data. I try and get python to reflect the class .. as I need to confirm its there for flask ..

below is what I type.

```
Python: 
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

Base.classes.keys()
```

I get nothing 
know why I am getting nothing I its because there is no class set up before I load the data using pandas ..

below is the code I use to load the data to  sqlite;

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///countrytwo.sqlite")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

file_name = 'us.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(file_name)

df.to_sql('us',con=engine, index_label='id', if_exists='replace')

## then to conform theirs data I do below ##
print (engine.table_names())
```

so do I know I need to set up the class first then load the data in to the sqlite file .. one does any one have a good webiste to do this ..

I would love a clue lead me to the answer but maybe not give me the answer ..
if this is unclear let me know I can load more code. thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
import sqlite3


    import pandas as pd
    import os

    class readCSVintoDB():

        def __init__(self):
            '''
            self.csvobj = csvOBJ
            self.dbobj = dbOBJ
            '''

            self.importCSVintoDB()

        def importCSVintoDB(self):

            userInput= input("enter the path of the csv file: ")
            csvfile = userInput
            df = pd.read_csv(csvfile,sep=';')

            #print("dataFrame Headers is {0}".format(df.columns))# display the Headers

            dp = (df[['date','temperaturemin','temperaturemax']])
            print(dp)

            '''
            check if DB file exist 
            if no create an empty db file
            '''
            if not(os.path.exists('./rduDB.db')):
                open('./rduDB.db','w').close()

            '''
            connect to the DB and get a connection cursor
            '''
            myConn = sqlite3.connect('./rduDB.db')
            dbCursor = myConn.cursor()

            '''
            Assuming i need to create a table of (Name,FamilyName,age,work)
            '''
            dbCreateTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rduWeather 
                               (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                                  Date varchar(256),
                                   TemperatureMin FLOAT,
                                   TemperatureMax FLOAT)'''

            dbCursor.execute(dbCreateTable)
            myConn.commit()


            '''
            insert data into the database
            '''
            for i in dp:
print(i)
                dbCursor.execute('''
                                  INSERT INTO  rduWeather VALUES (?,?,?,?)''', i)

            myConn.commit()

            mySelect=dbCursor.execute('''SELECT * from rduWeather WHERE (id = 10)''')
            print(list(mySelect))
            myConn.close()        


    test1 = readCSVintoDB()
```